# VStack extends its content layout. Is it possible to change a VStack's distribution?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In a nutshell, I'm trying to achieve the layout which on the left of the screenshot, but `VStack` extends its content (the right layout). Is it any way to adjust the distribution of `VStack` with the desired layout?

```swift
struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            SingleView(text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin lobortis tempor mi ultrices")
            SingleView(text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin lobortis tempor mi ultrices")
            SingleView(text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin lobortis tempor mi ultrices")
        }
    }
}

private struct SingleView: View {

    let text: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 4) {
                Capsule()
                    .cornerRadius(2)
                    .frame(width: 2)
                    .foregroundColor(.graphic)
                Circle()
                    .strokeBorder(Color.graphic, lineWidth: 2)
                    .frame(width: 12, height: 12)
                Capsule()
                    .cornerRadius(2)
                    .frame(width: 2)
                    .foregroundColor(.graphic)
            }
            Text(text)
                .body()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way for solving the issue:

```
struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
            
            HStack {
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {}, label: { Image(systemName: "trash").foregroundColor(.red) }).padding(.horizontal)
                
                Button(action: {}, label: { Image(systemName: "highlighter") })
                
            }
            .padding(10)
            
            SingleView(text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin lobortis tempor mi ultrices")
            SingleView(text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin lobortis tempor mi ultrices")
            SingleView(text: " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
            SingleView(text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin lobortis tempor mi ultrices")
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2).cornerRadius(15))
        .padding()
    }
}

private struct SingleView: View {
    
    let text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack { Text(text).padding(.leading, 24).padding(.bottom, 24); Spacer() }
            .overlay(
                
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0.0) {
                    
                    Circle()
                        .strokeBorder(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2)
                        .frame(width: 12, height: 12)
                        .padding(4)
                    
                    Capsule()
                        .frame(width: 2)
                    
                }
                , alignment: .leading)
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `maxHeight` for the `Capsule`s.

```
private struct SingleView: View {

    let text: String
    let maxHeight: CGFloat = 50 // <- HERE

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 4) {
                Capsule()
                    .cornerRadius(2)
                    .frame(width: 2)
                    .frame(maxHeight: maxHeight) // <- HERE
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                Circle()
                    .strokeBorder(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2)
                    .frame(width: 12, height: 12)
                Capsule()
                    .cornerRadius(2)
                    .frame(width: 2)
                    .frame(maxHeight: maxHeight) // <- HERE
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

---

#### Bonus

- The `Capsule()`s don't need to be given `cornerRadius(_:)`.
- To avoid the slight gaps between each `SingleView` because of the rounded capsules, set `View2`'s `VStack` spacing to `-2` (negative of capsule widths).